# IOS: animation that don't call completion quickly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiviewanimation

I have this code to simulate a multiple camera flash

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                      delay:0.f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                 animations:^{
                                [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:2];
                                flash.alpha=1.f;
                             }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                flash.alpha = 0;
                             }];
```

`flash` is a white `UIImageView` (*full screen*) that starts with `alpha = 0`.
If you try to use this code, you will notice that at the end flash remains full white for a little time and it's not perfect for my effects, what can I do to solve this?

Comment: maybe change `delay:0.f` to `delay:0.2f`

Comment: what do you exactly want then?

Comment: when this animation end I see a full white screen for a time that is so long...I want that disappear immediately

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is you do autoreverse using the option `UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse`, while also specifying your own final state in the completion block.

Try this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                 animations:^{
                                [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:2];
                                flash.alpha=1.f;
                             }
                 completion:nil];
```

Comment: @blackguardian I edited my answer. This code works (I've tested it by changing the duration to 1 second, and doing a large number of repetitions. The view fades in and out without blinking, or getting stuck.

Comment: @BlackRider : where is `completion:`? when you add it, ain't it the same as what he already has?

Comment: @staticVoidMan: should be an empty block. I'll edit the co.de

Comment: but... it's `+animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`. will it get the selector method `+animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:` ?

Comment: @staticVoidMan, you're right, I just updated the answer with the correct method signature. I don't know why it got lost :)

Comment: @BlackRider : ok, good catch on the `UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse` btw. _i wasn't aware of this_

Comment: I solved it!!! I start with alpha = 1 and I do animation reverse that finish with alpha = 0 ******* flash.alpha = 1;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 delay:0.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                     animations:^{
                         [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:2];
                         flash.alpha=0.f;
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
                             flash.alpha = 0;
                         }];
                     }];

Comment: Congrats! I recommend posting your solution as an answer and accept it, so people can easily find the solution :)